# How to use BulkMutateJob Service to create more than 800 Text Ads

Tags: php, google-ads-api, client-library

I am just checking into the Adwords API. My target is to create and manage 750 - 800 text ads  with some keyword corresponding to the product by fetching data from my database. I use PHP Client Library. I tried using the **adGroupAdService** mutate to create these ads with the data in *array* of **textAdGroupAdOperation**.

But i get

> "EntityCountLimitExceeded.ADGROUP_TEXT_AD_LIMIT
>   @ operations"

So i tried using the **BulkMutateJob** Service to accomplish this task by modifying the '**PerformBulkMutateJob**' example provided in the library. on running the script, i get the message like

> "Bulk mutate request with job id
>   "6700245679675929654" and part number
>   "0" was added. Unmarshalling Error:
>   cvc-type.2: The type definition cannot
>   be abstract for element
>   ns1:operations."

I don't know whether i'm in the correct direction. Please help me in fixing this issue and guide me in creating these Ads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `EntityCountLimitExceeded.ADGROUP_TEXT_AD_LIMIT` error means that you're adding too many ads into an ad group. You need to spread the ads out across multiple groups.